# how to send file using nfc in android

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam, open-nfc

I want to create an application to transfer files between two machines to each other via nfc android. 
My idea is to create an interface with a button that allows selected data (text, files, music ...) then when they click send to device and send. I have read the documentation in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#p2p. But still can not understand.If using it like android beam. Who can give me a better look at intelligibility, all contributions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You use NFC to exchange pairing information, like wifi credentials and an 'upload' url, not to do the actual transfer of data.

Answer (score 0):

Allows your app to send data over NFC. To specify this permission, add the following element as a child of the  element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

Comment: thanks, Can you recommend me an app with similar functionality?